# Knockout binding to checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a list of objects that need to be (un)checked by user:

```
var myList = [
    { id: 1, value: "aaa", checked: true}
    { id: 2, value: "bbb", checked: false}
    { id: 3, value: "ccc", checked: true}
]
```

Depending on user choice some business logic must be performed over the rest elements. It must be executed after any (un)check action so I need to know what exact element was affected.
I am using knockout.js and would like to display and bind values using this approach.
Checkbox "checked" binding can be done by 2 ways: by passing the boolean that will be automatically set according to user choice, or by passing an array whose content will expose what values were checked. I was unable to get the affected listed object and therefore run business logic in both cases.

1. When I pass a boolean to checkbox and it returns flat boolean so I couldn't know what listed object it belongs to
2. When I pass an observable array then I only can subscribe to its changes but in the handler I only have the whole array and still don't know what element was affected.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, just found that i can provide subscriptions with the context. The full syntax for subscribe is something like

```
observableItem.subscribe(function (newValue) {...}, context, stringVal)
```

where stringVal can be "beforeChange" that will subscribe you to the event before change. I didnt know that as they [don't document it](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables) at the official site. Btw anybody knows where the latest docs are?